# How to turn off monitor using DLL's entry points of windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, dll, rundll32.exe

As far as you know, we can call windows7 DLL's entry points via `rundll32 <dll-file>,<Entry point>` in command line. For example I lock my screen using below command in *Windows Command Line* :

`rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`

Now, I want to know if is there any way to turning off my monitor in such as this way? i.e. Is there any Entry-Point that I can call it in CMD and turn off my monitor?

Answer (score 3):

I dont see anyway to achieve this in win7 or later by using the rundll32, but you can use an external app called [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

To turn monitor off:

```
nircmd.exe monitor off
```

To turn monitor on:

```
nircmd.exe monitor on
```

You can put this in a bat file and make a shortcut of it.
You could also use a tool called [WIZMO](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) and use this in the command-line:

```
wizmo.exe monoff
```

Answer (score 2):

In the command line/ or as .bat/ .cmd / .com file:

`powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)`

As a direct powershell command, you can drop the escapes and powershell directive (and save as ps1 file as well.

`(Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)`

Of note this seems to leave a process forever running, that you need to either make sure you kill off later or something.  I am working on that issue now, which is how I stumbled here.  If I correct it I will leave an answer.