# Task Scheduler Monitor Off and Monitor On

Tags: display, tasks

I am trying to achieve something that I thought would be simple, but everything I try to use doesn't work.

Looking for a way to schedule a Monitor Off and Monitor On from task scheduler.

Very simple.  I'd like the monitor/screen to turn off at a specific time and turn back on at a specific time everyday.

Comment: Once upon a time I used a small utility for turning my monitors off with a key combo. Can't find the one I used anymore, but for example `doff` exists: https://sourceforge.net/projects/doff/

Comment: I'm gonna assume the monitor is external and plugs into a wall outlet. In that case, the simplest thing to do would probably be to just plug it into a timer switch.

Comment: Get a "smart plug" and program it accordingly to switch power ON/OFF right at the source as mentioned. Just look on Amazon or Walmart websites searching for "smart plugs". Otherwise see answers on duplicate SU post https://superuser.com/questions/887351/how-to-turn-off-monitor-using-dlls-entry-points-of-windows/1371383#1371383 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor.... read questions, answers, and all comments on all those posts. You can setup key combo with the logic that triggers, and then schedule that logic/script to execute via Task Scheduled as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You do not likely need to turn your monitor ON if no one is around and likewise turn it OFF at a specific time when you are using it.

Best to forget Task Scheduler for this - it was not designed to run monitors.

It will be vastly easier just to set the monitor to turn OFF after 5 or 10 minutes (I use 15 minutes) of no use. Turn it on with a keystroke or mouse movement.

Monitors were designed as I have described above.

Comment: I didn't ask for your opinion on what I likely need to do or not do, but thanks for your input anyway.  Its responses like these that make coming to boards for help so infuriating.  People ask for help with a specific problem, not to be told what they do or don't need to do.  I have a specific need for a specific task, and asked for help with it.  If you don't have anything to contribute towards my specific ask, best to not respond at all.

Comment: I may not have worded it the way you might like, but Task Scheduler is not a tool for what you are trying to do, that is, I do not think it will work.

Comment: It will work to trigger based on time and event. You will need 'more than just Task Scheduler alone' may have been better wording but wording in writing with no tone and demeanor is a matter of the reader's interpretation—I get it! Technically it is possible to schedule this with task scheduler but what task scheduler executes will likely be more complex, not Windows built-in, or a helper mechanism [api code] that controls the power source, disables the display adapter from the OS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### Looking for a way to schedule a Monitor Off and Monitor On from task scheduler.

You can use Nirsoft MultiMonitorTool:

> MultiMonitorTool is a small tool that allows you to do some actions related to working with multiple monitors. With MultiMonitorTool, you can disable/enable monitors, set the primary monitor, save and load the configuration of all monitors, and move windows from one monitor to another. You can do these actions from the user interface or from command-line, without displaying user interface.

Source: [Enable/disable/configure multiple monitors on Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)

See Also: [NirCmd Command Reference - monitor](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/monitor.html)